# What is the reason of error in importing Numpy though it installed correctly

Tags: numpy, import, python-3.5

```
when import numpy the following error was occur
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-35m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: cblas_sgemm

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
```

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

```
Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.5 from "/usr/bin/python3.5",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.18.1" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
```

Original error was: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-35m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: cblas_sgemm

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the error message: Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy and check the PATH and PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in error message, this error has many possible causes, but using `--no-use-pep517` option of `pip` was helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Huge delay, but delete the python2.7 folder from ~/.local/lib/ worked to me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).